# How to compile a Vue template with other components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

It's often needed to patch and compile a HTML (in my case a SVG) returned from a backend.

I used only the simplest version as

```
import {compile} from 'vue'; 
const component = compile(text);
```

But now I patch the source with DOM and inject other components inside it.
For that I need to use `app.component()` to register all the injected components.

That's bad obviously for several known reasons.

Could we inject locally imported components? Like:

```
import Tooltip from 'Tooltip.vue';
import {compile} from 'vue'; 
const component = compile(text, {components:[Tooltip]});
```

Definitely `compile` has an extensive set of options:

https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/fef2acb2049fce3407dff17fe8af1836b97dfd73/packages/compiler-core/src/options.ts

But I can't find anything about injecting components.

There are several ideas but need prolonged tries and errors like:

1. Compile as SFC and inject dependencies somehow
2. Provide components in `ctx` somehow on a render
3. Somehow do it with `defineComponent`

But I can't figure a proper direction to follow, any help would be appreciated.

The only working way I've found so far is with `<component>` but I'd like to use component names directly as tags (of cause I can patch the source to change custom components to `<component>` but anyway):

```
<script setup>
import { compile, h } from 'vue'

const comp = compile('<component :is="test"></component>');
const test = () => h('div', 'TEST');
</script>

<template>
  <comp :test/>
</template>
```

Comment: Is your `text` dynamic? i remember i posted a simple compiler for vue on stackoveflow you can find it

Comment: @TachibanaShin dynamic, found your compiler, will check it out, but thought there's some intrinsic Vue way to compile with custom components

Comment: What about parsing the svg(xml) to json  then using render function to render it?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim seems too complicated comparing to the using just `<component>`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Would be necessary in react but vue handles text templates much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compile` compiles a template to render function that resolves components by their names, i.e. `<SomeComp>` becomes `h(resolveComponent('SomeComp')`, this requires `SomeComp` component to be registered in the context where render function is used, this doesn't require special treatment from `compile`.

In this case it could be:

```
const DummyComponent = {
  name: 'DummyComponent',
  render: compile(`<div><SomeComp/></div>`),
  components: { SomeComp }
};
```

And rendered as any dynamic component, e.g. in a template:

```
<component :is="DummyComponent"></component>
```

Comment: Does this work with native web components as well?

Comment: @connexo I didn't test but I'd expect it to, this will require to provide config to compile() like discussed in the OP, like `compile(text, {isCustomElement() {...})`